# filename encoding using java

Tags: java, unix

I want to write a reversible Encoder along with the corresponding Decoder, so that any string may be encoded to a legal file name corresponding to file naming rules of the Unix file system.
How to achieve this?
Example:
"xyz.txt" would be a valid file name, while "xyz/.txt" would not.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**: Your approach is flawed. Stick with the limitations of the file system. They're pretty hard to gracefully overcome (especially without introducing your own, even weirder limitations).

---

It's not possible to make one that is strictly decodable. You're trying to map a larger domain to a smaller domain which means that the reverse mapping cannot be known-correctly reversible.

This is easy to demonstrate with a simple example: how do you encode `/` such that it can be reversed? "Easy," you might say, "I'll just replace with the token `x`." But now how do you know when an `x` is an actual `x` and when your `x` is a 'special' `x` that should be converted to `/`? You can't.

You can of course make a system that is very unlikely to have any accidental clashes. For example, rather than changing `/` to `-` (which would be very error prone), you could change it to `---`.

---

Oh, also, for what it's worth, most unix file systems actually consider any characters other than `/` or a null char a valid character ([more](https://serverfault.com/questions/150740/linux-windows-unix-file-names-which-characters-are-allowed-which-are-unesc)). Obviously using that is a pain in the ass though.